# iOS 7 - UISlider thumbTIntColor does not change

Tags: uikit, ios7, uislider

I am trying to change the Color of the Thumb on my UISlider - Somehow though, it always stays white. Changing the Color of the Bar itself seems to work quite well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  self.redSlider.thumbTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Am I missing something here?

I also found [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983726/uislider-thumbtintcolor-doesnt-change-on-ios-7-fine-on-ios-6) here, that indicates it could be a bug - any idea?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983726/uislider-thumbtintcolor-doesnt-change-on-ios-7-fine-on-ios-6 also

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's bug.
To avoid without preparing dummy image use this code.

```
[s setThumbImage:s.currentThumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
s.thumbTintColor = UIColor.redColor;
```

Comment: Although this hack works, it changes the thumb image to have a 3D effect like the old iOS 6 style. iOS 7 should have a flat style.

Comment: This approach isn't working in my scenario (within React Native). If I `setThumbImage` to an actual image in my `Images.xcassets` then it does work. Is there any alternative to `s.currentThumbImage`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up anything about it in a xib/storyboard ?

If yes instead of change it into the viewDidLoad, try to set your color into

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

If working, it's because this is called after loading values from storyboard, where viewDidLoad is called before.

Comment: This doesn't work, try it yourself, there doesn't exist a solution for it. It just wont change!

Comment: It fixed my project with it at that moment, sorry if doesn't work for you.